# mysql select if and

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm building a query on this table

```
my_table
field1 | field2
1      | y
2      | y
3      | y
4      | n
1      | n
2      | n
3      | y
4      | y
```

I am looking for a rule (maybe IF) to select all the records excluding the ones where field1=1 AND field2=y

this record will not be selected:

```
field1 | field2
1      | y
```

while this is ok

```
field1 | field2
1      | N
```

EDIT:

I add this details:
the query is longer:

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE time>'time1' AND time<'time2' AND admin_area='0'

in this query i have to append a filter:
if field2=Y exclude records where field1=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [The MySQL SELECT syntax reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)
You can also use != or <> for an inequality test.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (field1, field2) <> (1, 'y');`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE field1 <> 1 OR field2 <> 'y'
```

Comment: what about if i have a long where and rules before?

Comment: i know the not operato but can you show me a query for this case?

Comment: You could wrap this part into a long WHERE clause, such as: WHERE blah blah blah AND (field1 <> 1 OR field2 <> 'y') AND blah blah blah...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

> in this query i have to append a
>   filter: if field2=Y exclude records
>   where field1=1

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE time > 'time1'
AND   time < 'time2'
AND   admin_area = 0
AND ( (
    field2 = 'Y' AND field1 <> 1
) OR (
    field2 IS NULL OR field2 <> 'Y'
) )
```